# Probability of drawing exactly X previously unseen numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say we have $M$ balls, numbered $1$ to $M$, in a sack. Let us say we have already seen $Y$ of those balls. We now draw $N$ balls without replacement. What is the probability of seeing exactly $X$ previously unseen balls in this draw?

My thoughts so far. Total number of possible distinct draws is $\frac{M!}{N!(M-N)!}$. We are interested in all the draws that have exactly $X$ out of $M-Y$ balls, which should be ${M-Y}\choose{X}$. So the answer should be ${M-Y}\choose{X}$ / ${M}\choose{N}$. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to choose $X$ balls out of $M-Y$ and the remaining $N-X$ balls out of $Y$. The probability is 
$${{M-Y\choose X}{Y\choose N-X}\over{M\choose N}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Close: think about coloring the balls you have seen already red (let's assume the ones you haven't seen are black). Then, you must look to choose from only the black balls. As you have pointed out, there are $M - Y$ black balls, and $N \choose M$ total draws. We want to choose $N$ balls total, so we just fill the remaining $N - X$ slots with red balls. So instead we should have ${M - Y \choose X}{Y \choose N - X}$ as the numerator. If we look at it, it makes sense: if we try to draw more unseen balls than there are, i.e. $X > M-Y$, then we have zero possibilities.

This gives a final answer of $\displaystyle \frac{{M - Y \choose X}{Y \choose N - X}}{N \choose M}$ total possible draws satisfying this condition.